# Access non-public classes in sun.awt package [specifically: FetcherInfo]

Tags: java, security, awt, javax.imageio, securitymanager

**Question:**

I have some performance problem in my app - and the bottleneck is `sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run`, and I canno't get any (more) meaningfull info from profiler. So I figured that it would be nice to look at jobs that ImageFetcher is doing.

I couldn't get access to `FetcherInfo` class, that holds all `ImageFetcher` jobs. To obtain `FetcherInfo` instance I have to call `FetcherInfo.getFetcherInfo()`.

I created class in package `sun.awt.image` (just in my project, i didnt tinker with rt.jar).

To get `FetcherInfo` i use:

```
try{
   for(Method method : FetcherInfo.class.getDeclaredMethods()){
      method.setAccessible(true);
      if(method.getName().equals("getFetcherInfo")){
         m = method;
      }
   }
}catch (Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}

FetcherInfo info = null;
try {
   info = (FetcherInfo) m.invoke(null);
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And I get exception: `Exception in thread "IMAGE-FETCHER-WATCHER" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class sun.awt.image.FetcherInfo from class sun.awt.image.FetcherDebug`

And the stack trace points to:

```
for(Method method : FetcherInfo.class.getDeclaredMethods()){
```

The same exception was raised by:

```
 FetcherInfo.class.getMethod("getFetcherInfo");
```

So anyone has any ideas how to either:

- Obtain ImageFetcher instance
- Find out what images are getting loaded

**SOLUTION**

The problem was that i've put my class into `sun.java.awt` package to get access to package protected members, without putting it into `rt.jar`, and exception was thrown hen calling `ImageFetcher.class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access non-accessible members use `setAccessible(true)`. (Without a security manager present, there is no block on `sun.*` classes from being used with reflection.)

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Access {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class<?> imageFetcher = Class.forName("sun.awt.image.FetcherInfo");
        for (Method method : imageFetcher.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            ;
        }
        Method method = imageFetcher.getDeclaredMethod("getFetcherInfo");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        Object fetcher = method.invoke(null);
        System.err.println(fetcher);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you mean Method#setAccessible, i can't do it, because Exception is thrown before I get access to method instance (it occours on call to FetcherInfo.class.getDeclaredMethods()).

Comment: Works for me! What are you doing that is odd? Can you write a small yet complete example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Dumb, dumb, dumb me. 

All works now :) the problem was calling FetcherInfo.class.

Comment: I think we all do that sort of thing. Frequently.